# Can't return to main with multiple sub-programs

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to write a program in in MIPS assembly but I run into a problem when I have multiple jump and link instructions. For example:

```
main:
        jal 1
        or $0 $0 $0 #NO OP
1:
        jal 2
        or $0 $0 $0 #NO OP
        jr $ra
        or $0 $0 $0 #NO OP

2:
        jr $ra
        or $0 $0 $0 #NO OP
```

I understand that jal in 1 overwrites the address previously written in $ra but how would one go about getting back to the main function?

Comment: You normally write `$ra` to the stack and restore it from there before returning.

Comment: you must preserve the original `ra` value. Whether you keep it in other register, or store into memory is up to you, but usually memory pointed at by stack pointer is often used, because that can be easily used as LIFO queue, i.e. you naturally keep stacking new return address values when calling deeper levels of subroutines, and release that upon returning to upper levels.

Comment: this seems to cover the topic well: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse378/09wi/lectures/lec05.pdf

Answer (score 0):

use b main instead of jr $ra to go back to main

Comment: "don't use functions" is one answer, but it's not a *good* answer.  If code is only called once, you should just inline it (or make it a macro) instead of jumping to it in the first place.  (Unless it was a conditional branch).  But if it's called multiple times, you need to be able to return to the call site you came from.  (Or duplicate it at each call site, again with a an assembler macro)